# Different numbering for align and theorem environments

Tags: align, numbering, theorems

I would like to number align environments and theorems differently. E.g.the align environment following Theorem 2.1 is numbered 2.2. My preamble is attached in the following. I don't know what I have to change in order to decouple the nummeration. I would be grateful for any help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleq,12pt]{scrreprt}

 
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}


\usepackage{color}      

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm} 
\usepackage[all]{xy} 

\usepackage{setspace}         
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}   
\setlength{\parskip}{1.4ex plus 0.35ex minus 0.3ex} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Java,
    showstringspaces=false,
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\tiny}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\hyphenation{Sil-ben-trenn-ung}
```

Comment: You don't show how you define theorems. Possibly `\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly, this is where I have to make changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want that theorems and equations share the counter. Thus something like

```
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
```

will do the job.